# Поиск и заполнение грида . Зависание при цикличной повторной проверке. Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть поле из квадратов. Мне надо что бы алгоритм проверил поле и следом соседние поля от выбранного грида и заполнял ( вправо или влево) до окончания.

Сразу прошу сильно не бить из за рефакторинга. Я только учусь.Пришлось как то разбить код.

Проблема заключается в чём. При обработке этого кода Unity просто зависает.Думаю из за того что программа не имеет окончания из  за цикла в void FillPath. 
Помогите разобраться как правильно запустить проверку? что бы избежать( зависания и цикла). Или что б цикл окончился после проверки последнего элемента.

```
  void Search (GameObject[] EarthObjectsAll, Stack<GameObject> myStackPath, Vector3[] TestCoord1, 
   Stack<Vector3> mySosedStack, Vector3[] TestCoord, Stack<GameObject> myRecursiveStack) {
    // перебор объектов стака пути
    foreach (GameObject O in myStackPath) {
        // замена всех объектов пути на землю
        Instantiate(EarthObject, O.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
    //  запускаю алгоритм заполнения
    FillPath(EarthObjectsAll, mySosedStack, myRecursiveStack, EarthTagObjectsAll);
    // возвращаю индикатор окончания пути в нормальное состояние
    PassEndsIndenti = true;
}
```

Алгоритм пошагового заполнения.

```
void FillPath (GameObject[] EarthObjectsAll, Stack<Vector3> mySosedStack, Stack<GameObject> myRecursiveStack, GameObject[] EarthTagObjectsAll) {
    // переберем все объекты поля 
    foreach (GameObject D in EarthObjectsAll) {
        // получаем координаты объекта
        Vector3 ObjectPosition = D.transform.position;
        // переберем объекты соседей
        foreach (Vector3 V in mySosedStack) {
            //сравниваем позиции 
            if (ObjectPosition.Equals(V)) {
                // заполнение соседей
                Instantiate(EarthObject, ObjectPosition, Quaternion.identity);
                // координаты для генерации следующих соседей и их заливки 
                myRecursiveStack.Push(D);
            }
        }
    }
    //обнуляет стак соседей
    mySosedStack = new Stack<Vector3>();
    //Перебираю 
    foreach (GameObject L in myRecursiveStack) {
        //Генерирую координаты соседей
        GenCoordsMet(L, TestCoord, mySosedStack);
    }
    // Запускаю алгоритм заново
    FillPath(EarthObjectsAll, mySosedStack, myRecursiveStack, EarthTagObjectsAll);
}
```

Добавляю в стак для последующей  цикличной обработки mySosedStack.

```
  void GenCoordsMet (GameObject thatObgect, Vector3[] TestCoord, Stack<Vector3> mySosedStack) {
    // координаты  объекта земли
    Vector3 Pozition = thatObgect.transform.position;
    // наполнение массива координатами соседей
    TestCoord = GenCoordTest(Pozition);
    //Добавление координат объектов для следующего шага
    foreach (Vector3 G in TestCoord) {
        // создает следующий шаг соседей
        mySosedStack.Push(G);
    }
}
```

Генерирую координаты по оси Х

```
 Vector3[] GenCoordTest (Vector3 T) {
    // объявим массив из 4 точек
    Vector3[] S = new Vector3[1];
    //правая точка(координаты справа)
    S[0] = T; S[0].x++;
    return S;
}
```

Comment: Добавьте тег unity3d к вопросу.

Comment: Такие вещи решаются отладкой. Ставите точку останова на вход в метод и далее продвигаетесь шагами вперед и смотрите значения переменных, ищите где что-то не так. Или используете `Debug.WriteLine(....);` для вывода значений переменных в окно `Output`.

Comment: Отладкой очень проблематично получилось отслеживать. Так как у меня в программе много переборов объектов . И в некоторых массивах и стеках есть около 200 объектов. И  при каждом сравнение приходиться жать F11. Но было очень познавательно в этом разобраться.Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак я пошел другим путём. 
Спасибо Yaroslav навел меня на мысль. 
Спасибо Bulson за идею отладки.

Немного по шаманив убрал путаницу и с отладкой и переписав код.Я все таки добился нужного эффекта.
Вставляю части кода может кому пригодиться . Кому интересно что я Творю или если есть идеи как это дело всё улучшить . Буду рад поделиться ссылкой на гитхаб и если что буду рад  научиться чему то новому.

```
 if (PassEndsIndenti == false)// при остановке  запускаю скрипт замены всех тайтлов пути на тайтлы  земли
        {

            foreach (GameObject O in myStackPath)// перебор объектов стека пути
            {
                Debug.Log(myStackPath.Count + "myStackPath.Count");

                Vector3 Pozition = O.transform.position;// координаты  объекта земли 

                TestCoord = GenCoordTest(Pozition);// наполнение массива координатами соседей 

                foreach (Vector3 T in TestCoord) Debug.Log(T + "TestCoord1");// Координаты соседей
                Debug.Log(TestCoord.Length + "TestCoord.Length 1");

                foreach (Vector3 G in TestCoord)
                {
                    myVectorSosedStack.Push(G); // создает следующий шаг соседей
                }
            }

            NewMethod();

            myVectorSosedStack = new Stack<Vector3>();//обнуляем стек
            myStackPath = new Stack<GameObject>();//обнуляем стек
            PassEndsIndenti = true;// возвращаю индикатор окончания пути в нормальное состояние

        }
```

Идея кода сверху. При  команде "PassEndsIndenti=false" при остановке  запускаю скрипт замены всех тайтлов пути на тайтлы  земли.И в последствии генерирую координаты соседей добавляя их в стек для проверки. И далее запускаем метод заливки NewMethod().

```
void NewMethod()
{
    foreach (Vector3 V in myVectorSosedStack)// переберем объекты соседей
    {

        foreach (GameObject D in ObjectsAll)// переберем все объекты в ObjectsAll
        {
            Vector3 ObjectPosition = D.transform.position;// получаем координаты объекта


            if (ObjectPosition == V)//сравниваем позиции 
            {
                Instantiate(PathObject, ObjectPosition, Quaternion.identity);// заполнение соседей

                Debug.Log(ObjectPosition + "ObjectPosition");

                foreach (GameObject W in myStackAllEarthBlockObject)// проверяем объекты myStackAllEarthBlockObject
                {
                    Vector3 blockPosition = W.transform.position;

                    if (blockPosition == ObjectPosition) //если объект который сгенерировался упёрся в другой объект

                    {
                        Debug.Log("ObjectPosition == blockPosition");
                        AAAA = true;// Затычка для  блокировка следующего когда если ObjectPosition == blockPosition 
                        break;  
                    }
                }


                if (AAAA != true)
                {
```

Тут часть можно заменить на метод кому не лень.От сюда ...

```
                    TestCoord = new Vector3[] { };
                    myVectorSosedStack = new Stack<Vector3>();


                    Vector3 Pozition = D.transform.position;// координаты  объекта земли 

                    TestCoord = GenCoordTest(Pozition);// наполнение массива координатами соседей 
                    foreach (Vector3 G in TestCoord)

                    {
                        myVectorSosedStack.Push(G);
                    }
```

До

```
                    NewMethod();//перезапускаем метод заливки 

                }

                // Debug.Log("ObjectPosition != blockPosition");
                break;// прерываем поиск 
            }

        }
    }
    AAAA = false;// возвращаем значение для последующих повторений кода .
}
```

И  метод перебора координат.Или генерации .

```
void GenCoordsMet(GameObject thatObgect)
{
    Debug.Log(TestCoord.Length + "GenCoordsMet");

    Vector3 Pozition = thatObgect.transform.position;// координаты  объекта земли 
    TestCoord =  GenCoordTest(Pozition);// наполнение массива координатами соседей 

    foreach (Vector3 G in TestCoord)
    {
        myVectorSosedStack.Push(G); // создает следуюший шаг соседей
        Debug.Log(myVectorSosedStack.Count);
    }
}

 Vector3[] GenCoordTest(Vector3 T)
{
    Vector3[] S = new Vector3[1];/*Объявим массив из 4 точек*/


    S[0] = T; S[0].x++; //правая точка

   // S[1] = T; S[1].x--; //левая точка

   // S[2] = T; S[2].y++; //верхняя точка

   // S[3] = T; S[3].y--; //нижняя точка 

    return S;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В конце метода `FillPath` ты вызываешь ещё один `FillPath` (это называется рекурсия).

Второй метод вызывает третий и т.д. до бесконечности подобно циклу `while (true) {}`.

Команда `return;` остановит выполнение даже `void` метода и необходимо добавить условие для конца цикла.