# Способы ограничения заливки гридов Floodfill

Tags: c#, unity3d

Появилась проблема. С ограничением заливки.
**Подскажите как реализовать способ ограничения распространения заливки .**

### Мне нужно что бы заполнялось только поле которое создаёт игрок.

### [image: Поле игры.]

У меня есть поле и игрок "G" игрок двигаясь по полю создаёт путь из "Er зелёных "объектов(путь отмечен красной стрелкой).В последствии это поле заливается "Er синими" объектами.

А алгоритм заливки .Игнорирует поля так как проверяется для каждого объекта в массиве путь.И проверяется с лева на право .

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

То есть рекурсивный поиск и заливка линейная floodfill.
 Крестиком отмечен  объект "стоп" . А если  ограничиваю распространение координаторами массива то поле просто не заполняется.

Есть идея переделать алгоритм  заполнения на нелинейный а всесторонний ( то есть каждый грид будет проверять соседей с четырёх сторон.)Но столкнулся с проблемой при ограждении поля для заливки , первый грид с которого стартует проверка ,для всех остальных ,нужно поместить в центр поля которое нужно залить.

Comment: Вы используете `RawImage`?

Comment: Если можно оставьте код заливки

Comment: @Арман [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1111374/Поиск-и-заполнение-грида-Зависание-при-цикличной-повторной-проверке-unity) вот тут в теме я боролся с проблемой зависания. В ответе  я вложил тот код который у меня получился.С описанием как работает.

Comment: Разбираться в том хаосе целый день не очень хочетсяНужно найти проблему и работать с ней, а не со всем сразу(очень много всего там). Покажите пожалуйста код, где вы проверяете path свой и вы это делаете с помощью `GridLayoutGroup` ?

Comment: @Methorn фактически весь  NewMethod(); это делает

Comment: @Methorn , я могу разбить код на действия если вам будет удобно .